# Setting up .htaccess on host for execution of C++ cgi scripts

Tags: c++, .htaccess, cgi, bluehost

I have a cgi script that I know works (as far as the code is concerned), but which cannot be accessed through my website.  My hosting provider simply states that I need to edit the .htaccess file, but I have no idea what options/handlers I need to set in order to make the contents of a directory execute like c++.

How is this done?

Comment: If you replace the compiled executable of your C++ program with any other CGI script you will see the same problem. This really has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: Maybe you want to add this? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't on this service provider.  A quick search of the Bluehost Kb gave this: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/48

> Our LINUX web servers have the capability to run CGI scripts in your own "cgi-bin" directory. Scripts may be written in Perl, Python and CGI languages.
>
> Here are some helpful tips to follow when installing scripts:
>
> - Upload to your cgi-bin directory to ensure proper file permission settings.
> - All scripts on our server must have permissions set to 755 (rwx-rx-rx). If you need help in changing script permissions, please see our article about setting file and user permissions.
> - Upload in ASCII transfer mode (and NOT BINARY mode)
>     The first line of each script must read: a) #!/usr/bin/perl (for Perl) b) #!/usr/bin/python (for Python)
> - Ensure the permissions are set to 755

However, there is nothing stopping you just trying just putting your exe in the cgi-bin dir and seeing if it runs, but this probably won't work.

In this case, you'd need to relink any C++ against the local target server, and I doubt that Bluehost would facilitate this -- just too much support hassle for the few $ / month that you pay.

Comment: I finally did get it to work, and it didn't require any fancy footwork either with the .htaccess files.  Because they already allow cgi scripts to run, anything that is executable can be run in the cgi-bin directories if they are called through http requests.  They also have the gcc compiler on their servers, and they allow ssh connections, so I was able to put my code where it needed to go and compile it in place.  After that, it didn't take long for me to get it working.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  You're lucky. AFAIK, most *shared* hosting providers disable this sort of functionality.  I've just checked the one that I use for my blog engine and it has gcc disabled for hosted accounts.